# How to return Repository Objects as Json on Symfony2

Tags: json, symfony

I'm trying to return the users like this, but of course it doesn't work, I need the data as JSon since im working with BackboneJs

```
/**
* @Route("/mytest",name="ajax_user_path")
*/
public function ajaxAction()
{
    $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    $users = $this->get('doctrine')->getRepository('GabrielUserBundle:Fosuser')->findAll();

    $response = array("users"=>$users);            
    return new Response(json_encode($response));
}
```

Comment: Generally `User` object is huge. Are you sure that you need all this information? It would makes troubles for browsers.

Comment: I recommend you if you are using Symfony2 as a backend and you need an API you should  definitely try out this [bundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRest)... It's easy to use and to setup. And as an extra you can also generate a nice [documentation](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle) for it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks for your help guys, here is the Solution 
Get the JMSSerializerBundle,

This is the code on the controller

```
/**
     * @Route("/user")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function userAction()
    {
        $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
        $users = $this->get('doctrine')->getRepository('GabrielUserBundle:Fosuser')->findAll();

        $serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');
        $response = $serializer->serialize($users,'json');

        return new Response($response);
    }
```

Comment: On symfoyn4 the serializer chages like this: $serializer = $this->get('serializer');

Answer (score 5):

So, `findAll` [returns](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.4/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityRepository.html#158-166) an array of entities (objects) and `json_encode` cannot correctly encode that array. You have to prepare your data berofe send response like that:

Example:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

/**
* @Route("/mytest",name="ajax_user_path")
*/
public function ajaxAction()
{
    $users = $this->get('doctrine')->getRepository('GabrielUserBundle:Fosuser')->findAll();
    $response = array();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $response[] = array(
            'user_id' => $user->getId(),
            // other fields
        );
    }

    return new JsonResponse(json_encode($response));
}
```

Moreover, it would be great if you put preparing response to ex. `UserRepository` class.

Answer (score 0):

With Symfony you have JsonResponse like :

```
return new JsonResponse($users);
```

And don't forget to add the header :

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
```

Comment: it returns a value like this "{"users":[{},{}]}"
the same as in the example =/

Comment: Are you sure $users is good ? Try a var_dump just before the return

Comment: $users must be an array

Comment: just dumped the users variable it does return an array of users

Comment: Can you edit with your new code and if possible an example of the dump of $users

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried to encode a complete object, but I have used json with arrays of informations like this:

```
$vars = array( 
   'test' => 'test'
);            
$response = new JsonResponse($vars);

return $response;
```

As you can see in JsonResponse, its function `setData()` is encoding the array, so you don't have to do it yourself:

```
public function setData($data = array())
{
    // Encode <, >, ', &, and " for RFC4627-compliant JSON, which may also be embedded into HTML.
    $this->data = json_encode($data, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_QUOT);

    return $this->update();
}
```