# How to avoid serializer to escape double quote to \u0022?

Tags: php, symfony

In my controller I want to return a `JsonResponse`:

```
public function index(CkeditorTemplateRepository $ckeditorTemplateRepository, SerializerInterface $serializer): Response
{
    $data = $ckeditorTemplateRepository->findAll();
    return new JsonResponse($serializer->serialize($data, 'json'));
}
```

But when I request this endpoint, the response includes too many `\u` prefixes:

> "[{\u0022created\u0022:\u00222019-08-31T07:28:56+00:00\u0022,\u0022id\u0022:1,\u0022content\u0022:\u0022\u003Ctr\u003E\u003Ctd height=\\u002252\\u0022 valign=\\u0022bottom\\u0022 class=\\u0022h24\\u0022\u003E\u003Cspan class=\\u0022h21copy1\\u0022\u003E\u5b66\u4e60\u56de\u526f\u603b\u7406\u7684\u8bb2\u8bdd \u003C\/span\u003E\u003C\/td\u003E\u003C\/tr\u003E\u003Ctr\u003E\u003Ctd valign=\\u0022top\\u0022\u003E\u003Cp style=\\u0022margin-bottom:10\\u0022 align=\\u0022center\\u0022 class=\\u0022font6\\u0022\u003E\u003C\/p\u003E\u003C\/td\u003E\u003C\/tr\u003E\u0022}]"

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21672436/how-to-return-repository-objects-as-json-on-symfony2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing it wrong.

`JsonResponse` is a response object that helps you with serializing the response data to JSON.

But you are already doing the seralization yourself, so it is a bit redundant.

Couple of options:

```
return (new Response($serializer->serialize($data, 'json'))
    ->headers->set('Content-type', 'application/json');
```

Or if you keep using `JsonResponse`:

```
return (new JsonResponse())->setContent($serializer->serialize($data, 'json'));
```

Or instantiate `JsonResponse` directly from [a factory method](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/a1cce5a8b410d3a760bd86bf9250236858a7905d/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/JsonResponse.php#L75):

```
return JsonResponse::fromJsonString($serializer->serialize($data, 'json'));
```

(in either case, no need to set the content type, since JsonResponse does that for you.)

If you do:

```
new JsonResponse($data);
```

what you get is a response where the `content` is the JSON serialiazed `$data`. This works for **simple data structures** which you can easily serialize by calling `json_encode`. But you were already sending a JSON string, so by doing it this way you were serializing the data twice.

Comment: `new JsonResponse($data);` seems not works for entity results, it returns nothing

Comment: As I mentioned, that's only for simple data structures, not for complex ones like doctrine entities/collections. You should use one of the other alternatives I offered you in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`return new JsonReponse($data)` deals with arrays, strings etc. It will `json_encode` 
that data for output. With a pre-serialised string, you can use `return JsonResponse::fromJsonString('{"key": "value"}')`. Both accept a $status and an array of headers.

`JsonResponse::fromJsonString()` is, in fact, just a shortcut for calling the constructor with its final parameter with true.

```
__construct($data = null, int $status = 200, array $headers = [], bool $json = false)
```

Comment: `return new JsonReponse($data)` seems not work with entity, it returns nothing